# Card array toString - Java

Tags: java, arrays, playing-cards

I'm struggling to implement a toString method to output a deck of cards (ARRAY).

I have a Card Class

```
public class Card {

    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    public Card(Rank theRank, Suit theSuit) {
        rank = theRank;
        suit = theSuit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (rank + " of " + suit);
    }

}
```

Ranks implemented as Enums

```
public enum Rank {

    ACE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(
            9), TEN(10), JACK(10), QUEEN(10), KING(10);

    private final int rankValue;

    private Rank(int value) {
        rankValue = value;
    }

    public int getRankValue() {
        return rankValue;
    }

}
```

Suits implemented as Enums

```
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS, SPADES;
}
```

A Deck Class

```
public class Deck {

    private static Card[] cards = new Card[52];

    public Deck() {
        int i = 0;
        for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
            for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
                cards[i++] = new Card(r, s);

            }
        }
    }

    public Card[] getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    // toString METHOD NOT WORKING
    public String toString() {

        String s = ("The Complete Deck consists of: \n" + getCards());

        return s;

    }

}
```

And a DeckDriver Class (including the main method)

```
public class TestDeck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("*** DISPLAY A FULL DECK OF CARDS ***\n");

        Deck theDeck = new Deck();

        Card[] cards = theDeck.getCards();

        for (Card c : theDeck.getCards()) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

        // or
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(theDeck.toString());

    }

}
```

The first println statement prints out as desired, but I'm required to implement a toString() method in the Deck Class. This is where I am having difficulty.

From the code above (& excluding the output from the first println statement), the output I am getting is:

The Complete Deck consists of: 
[LCard;@2c6f7ce9

Any advice to enable me to understand & correct this issue would be great.

Thanks.

*** EDIT ***

So I tried the following:

```
public String toString() {

    String s = ("The Complete Deck consists of: \n" + Arrays
            .toString(cards));
    return s;

}
```

& it outputs the array, but in a single, w i d e, long line. Is there any way to print each array element on a new line?

Thanks.

Comment: check my answer. I modified it as per your requirements

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the output of toString for an array.  You need to iterate each item in your Card array and output its toString value.  Or you could use the method from [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and call `Arrays.toString(getCards());`

If you don't like the output then you'll have to do the iteration and output yourself (or use something from apache commons or guava or something to join the array values into a nice, readable String.

Something like this should work:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( "The Complete Deck consists of: \n" );
    for ( Card card : getCards() ) {
      buf.append( card.toString()).append( "\n" );
    }
    return buf.toString();
}
```

or with [apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) :

```
public String toString() {
    return "The Complete Deck consists of: \n" + StringUtils.join( getCards(), "\n" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could You direct me on how I may iterate through the array in the way You suggest?

Comment: Much appreciated!
I'm not yet familiar with StringBuilder, but it's something I will investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here. I would prefer the second one:

Either change your **getCards()** method to

```
public String getCards(){
    return Arrays.deepToString(cards);
}
```

Better you can do something like this in your **toString()** method

```
public String toString() {

    String s = ("The Complete Deck consists of: \n" + Arrays.deepToString(getCards()));

    return s;

}
```

What this `Arrays.deeptoString()` does is it provides you a string representation of the array.

**Update 1**: - Below is the code which prints each element on new line.

```
public String toString(int[] arr) {
        String temp = "";
        for (int i : arr) {
            temp = temp + i + "\n";
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

**Update 2**: - My first update was to give you an idea about how you can get a string that has elements from array on new line. Seems like people want me to give you the exact code that you can paste in your program and get it running

```
 public String toString() {
            String temp = "";
            for (Card c : Cards) {
                temp = temp + c.toString() + "\n";
            }
            return temp;
        }
```

Comment: Why an int array?  And why not override the inherited toString?

Comment: It is an example how he can achieve printing array elements on different lines. @sdanzig check what is the heading of the code. It states its use case. It is not a replacement for what the user wants but rather how a way of achieving what he wants.

Comment: Okay, it's leaving him to think a little, fine, but why would you define toString with an argument?  I think it's confusing for someone learning Java to see that, because if they ever try to do that on their own, passing in an argument, it won't override Object.toString() which is almost always the intention.

Comment: And if it was your reason for a downvote reconsider it and if there is anything else wrong with the code let me know. For your comment I wanted to let him know how can he return a string which displays elements in new line. But for me get it running it is the easiest way to test it

Comment: I appreciate your response, & further updates. It's interesting to see the for loop used in a different context.

Comment: @user2904978 If you feel my answer is what you were looking for feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Java's native arrays do not implement "toString()" by default.  You have to do that manually, by adding the toStrings() of the cards individually in a loop and returning that, or by doing something like Arrays.toString as suggested in another answer.

If you want the cards displayed on separate lines, you have to implement your own loop like this:

```
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    for(Card c: cards) {
        str += c.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a toString method in the Card Class - the bottom / last function. At least it's named toString(). Am I missing some understanding of how a 'proper' toString method is to be implemented?

Comment: No, it was fine, @user2904978 ... I reformatted your code.. the indentation confused me horribly.  See my solution to have the cards display on separate lines though.

Answer (score 1):

To concatenate String with some non-String object Java uses result of `toSrting()` method of that `non-string` object. So it is the same as `"myString" + someObject.toStrint()`. In your case you are trying to do

```
"The Complete Deck consists of: \n" + getCards()
```

and since `getCards()` returns `Card[]` array Java will invoke `toString()` on that array.
Arrays will not let you to override its `toString()` method and will use its inherited from Object class version which returns

```
getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

so you are seeing `[LCard;@2c6f7ce9` which means

- one dimensional array `[L`
- of `Card` type objects
- and its `hashCode` in hexadecimal format is `2c6f7ce9`.

---

If you want to create String that will be representation of elements inside array you can use `Arrays.toString(yourArray)` or just iterate over all elements of array and concatenate them.

So maybe change your `toString()` method in `Deck` class to something like

```
public String toString() {
    return  "The Complete Deck consists of: \n" + Arrays.toString(getCards());
}
```

or if you want each card in new line

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("The Complete Deck consists of: ");
    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(cards[i].toString()).append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    sb.append(cards[cards.length - 1]);

    return sb.toString();
}
```